How to use Component-Driven Outlets from inside a Lazy Module?
I would like to provide a Component-Driven Outlet from a Lazy module by using the following syntax:
providers: [
  provideOutlet({
    id: 'header',
    position: OutletPosition.REPLACE,
    component: CustomHeaderComponent,
  }),
]

And then use it outside, from another Lazy module. Does Spartacus support it? If yes, where can I find a live example?
P.S. All the Component-Driven Outlets that exist in the application at the moment and belong to Lazy modules are provided in Root, which makes the component not lazy.
